# can't install android sdk

Tags: android-emulator

I'm trying to install the android sdk but it's complaining that it can't find the java se jdk.  I've installed it and rebooted so I don't know why it can't find it.  No, I didn't install just java, I made sure it was the sdk.  I did notice that nothing was updated in my environment variables path... but I'm not sure if anything would be added there or not.  Does anyone know how to get the sdk to see the jdk?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install x86 version of JDK. It seems you have installed JDK for 64bit Windows.